# How can I compare two lists 1 by 1 and then output false or true if they are the same

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to take a list like `['1', '2', '3', '4']` and `['5', '6', '7', '4']` and then in order compare them 1 by 1. `1 ≠ 5` next one `2 ≠ 6`, `3 ≠ 7`, `4=4`. I want the output to be which ones are not equal such as `['-', '-', '-', '4']`.

Comment: Do you want to output to be `['-', '-', '-', '4']` or of boolean format `[False, False, False, True]`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read [ask] and [mre].

Comment: why was this question closed? the question is clear and the expected output is clear.

Comment: @12944qwerty I want there to be a count at the end of how many falses or dashes there are so I don't know which one would be easier to do that with

Answer (score 1):

You can `zip()` and a list comprehension to compare each element pairs:

```
list_1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
list_2 = [3, 4, 5, 6, 4]

lists_compared = [x if x==y else "-" for (x,y) in zip(list_1, list_2)]

# output: ['-', '-', '-', '-', 4]
```

Comment: This seems to work how I wanted it to, I will do further testing but thank you so much for this answer

Comment: The only thing I would think I need in this is a way to do different length lists but I don't know how hard that would be to do.

Comment: you need a different algorithm to compare them, i.e. dropping the exceeding values in the longest list

Comment: then you can try sort the lists. check sorted() function

Comment: Couldn't I just count how many are exceeding the list? Because I am trying to find the amount of differences